# Write to Joomla database

Tags: php, mysql, json, joomla

I have a cool component for joomla that help me register users by creating a url (see the link). 
[joomla extention](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/mobile/mobile-apps/hoicoi-api)

What i would like to do is to be able to write on a different table using the same method:
This is the code that help with user registration:

```
//http://YOURSITE.COM/index.php?option=com_hoicoiapi&task=registration&name=NAME&username=USERNAME&passwd=PASSWORD&email=EMAIL
public function registration()
{
    $name = JRequest::getVar('name');
    $username = JRequest::getVar('username');
    $passwd = JRequest::getString('pass');
    $email = JRequest::getVar('email');


    $data = array(
          "name"=>$name,
          "username"=>$username,
          "password"=>$passwd,
          "password2"=>$passwd,
          "email"=>$email,
          "block"=>1,
          "groups"=>array("2"),
          "sendEmail"=>("1"),
        );

    $user = new JUser;
    //Write to database
    if(!$user->bind($data)) {
        $status = "Could not bind data. Error: " . $user->getError();
    }
    if (!$user->save()) {
      $status = "Could not save user. Error: " . $user->getError();
    }
    else {
      $status = "Success";
    }

    $message = array(
        'message' => $status
        );

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode ($message);
    jexit();
}
```

To be more explicit, i would like to be able to write comments in a table called belvw_zoo_comment
Is there a way to do that by just modifying the above code? i m thinking of something like this:

```
     //http://YOURSITE.COM/index.php?option=com_hoicoiapi&task=comment&author=AUTHOR&email=EMAIL&content=CONTENT
   public function comment()
  {
  $author = JRequest::getVar('author');
  $email = JRequest::getVar('email');
  $content = JRequest::getVar('content');


  $data = array(
       "author"=>$author,
       "email"=>$email,
       "content"=>$content,

        );

   $comment = new comment;
   //Write to database
   if(!$comment->bind($data)) {
       $status = "Could not bind data. Error: " . $user->getError();
    }
    if (!$comment->save()) {
      $status = "Could not save user. Error: " . $user->getError();
    }
    else {
     $status = "Success";
    }

    $message = array(
       'message' => $status
       );

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode ($message);
    jexit();
}
```

Of course the above code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that eventually worked for me:

```
public function event()
{
    //$id = JRequest::getVar('id');
    $ide = JRequest::getVar('ide');
    $name = JRequest::getVar('name');
    $email = JRequest::getVar('email');
    $confirmed = JRequest::getVar('confirmed');
    $quantity = JRequest::getVar('quantity');



    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


    //Custom Joomla code for inseting to comment table starts

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    // Create a new query object.
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    // Insert columns.
    $columns = array('ide', 'name','email','confirmed', 'ip','date'); // table column names

    // Insert values.
    $values = array($db->quote($ide), $db->quote($name), $db->quote($email), $db->quote($confirmed), $db->quote($ip) , $db->quote($date)); // values 

    // Prepare the insert query.
    $query
        ->insert($db->quoteName('#__rseventspro_users'))
        ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
        ->values(implode(',', $values));

    // Set the query using our newly populated query object and execute it.
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $message=$db->execute();
    $last_id = $db->insertid();


    $query1 = $db->getQuery(true);

    // Insert columns.
    $columns1 = array('ids', 'quantity'); // table column names

    // Insert values.
    $values1 = array($db->quote($last_id), $db->quote($quantity)); // values 



    // Prepare the insert query.
    $query1
        ->insert($db->quoteName('#__rseventspro_user_tickets'))
        ->columns($db->quoteName($columns1))
        ->values(implode(',', $values1));

    // Set the query using our newly populated query object and execute it.
    $db->setQuery($query1);
    $message=$db->execute();



    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode ($message);
    jexit();
    //Custom Joomla code for inseting to comment table starts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of your code add:

```
$comment = JRequest::getVar('comment');
```

Then inside the success clause add the following block

```
$db     = JFactory::getDbo();
$query  = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->insert('#__zoo_comment');
$query->set('name_of_field = '.$db->quote($comment));

$db->setQuery( $query );
$db->execute();
```

You would have to change the name of 'name_of_field' to the name of your field and it assumes that the comment is in a field called 'comment' in the form submitted.

So you would get:

```
public function registration()
{
    $name = JRequest::getVar('name');
    $username = JRequest::getVar('username');
    $passwd = JRequest::getString('pass');
    $email = JRequest::getVar('email');
    $comment = JRequest::getVar('comment');

    $data = array(
          "name"=>$name,
          "username"=>$username,
          "password"=>$passwd,
          "password2"=>$passwd,
          "email"=>$email,
          "block"=>1,
          "groups"=>array("2"),
          "sendEmail"=>("1"),
        );

    $user = new JUser;
    //Write to database
    if(!$user->bind($data)) {
        $status = "Could not bind data. Error: " . $user->getError();
    }
    if (!$user->save()) {
      $status = "Could not save user. Error: " . $user->getError();
    }
    else {
      $status = "Success";

        //Save comment
        $db     = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query  = $db->getQuery(true);

        $query->insert('#__zoo_comment');
        $query->set('name_of_field = '.$db->quote($comment));

        $db->setQuery( $query );
        $db->execute();


    }

    $message = array(
        'message' => $status
        );

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode ($message);
    jexit();
}
```